# pyftpsync adding ESC character in output

Tags: python, unicode, pyftpsync

I want to sync my ftp with a local folder along with logs. The logs getting saved as well as the console shows ESC character added like this in end of every line when it checks a file.

```
vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/language/phpmailer.lang-eo.php[0m[0K
```

[Here is output screenshot in sublime as I am unable to paste ESC in browser here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuyQl.png)

Here is my code.

```
from ftpsync.targets import FsTarget
from ftpsync.ftp_target import FtpTarget
from ftpsync.synchronizers import DownloadSynchronizer

import logging
import logging.handlers
from ftpsync.util import set_pyftpsync_logger

custom_logger = logging.getLogger("my.logger")
log_path = "D:\\pyftpsync.log"
handler = logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler(log_path)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
custom_logger.addHandler(handler)

set_pyftpsync_logger(custom_logger)


local = FsTarget("D:\\ftptest")
user =""
passwd = ""
remote = FtpTarget("/public_html/", "example.com", username=user, password=passwd)
opts = {"force": False, "delete_unmatched": True, "progress": True, "verbose": 4}
s = DownloadSynchronizer(local, remote, opts)
s.run()
```

What might be causing that?

Answer (score 1):

These sequences starting with ESC are actually ANSI sequences that can be used to display colored text (and other text effects) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

The problem is that the sublime environment you are running this into is not processing these sequences - instead, it is expanding the ESC character (`chr(0x1b)`) to the highlited "ESC" string.

If you run your same code in the actual terminal, instead of from inside sublime's terminal emulator, these will be changed to the actual color-changing sequences and you should have a nice output.

Other than that, since the output is generated by the `ftpsync` library code, your option would be to check for options in the call to  create the `DownloadSyncronizer` that would suppress the color output altogether.

Comment: That makes sense. I am running it in Windows CMD though and the logger is saving a .log file as well. Even the log file contains it and even when using no-color flag with ftpsync, results are same...

Comment: Which ftpsync version are you using? I tried to look for it to see if I could identify a workaround, but I got to an "ftpsmartsync" thing that features no `DownloadSynchronizer` class.

Comment: Did you try to set ‘progress’ to false?